# How many cycles are possible in an unlabeled complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, permutation-cycles

I have found that the number of cycles for an unlabeled graph is ${n\choose m}\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$.
n: Number of vertices in the graph
m: The length of the cycle we need to determine.

Comment: That’s correct if you don’t distinguish a starting point.

Comment: I do not understand (nCm*(n-1)!)/2. Someone please edit the question and include LaTeX.

Comment: @Vlad I think it reads $(\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{m} \cdot (n-1)!)$.

Comment: I suspect there's a small mistake, according to OEIS the $(n-1)!$ should be an $(m-1)!$, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite right, the correct answer (as you an check on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002807)) is that in the complete graph $K_n$, the number of cycles of length $k$ ($3\leq k \leq n$) is:

$$\binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{(k-1)!}{2}$$

Here's a derivation:

- First, we need to pick a vertex set for our $k$-cycle. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose a $k$-set from the vertex set of $K_n$.
- Having chosen $k$ vertices for the cycle, we need to find the order in which the cycle traverses those vertices. There are $k!$ ways to order the $k$ vertices, so we have a total of $\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!$ orderings.
- Not every ordering uniquely determines a cycle. Each cycle can be represented by exactly $2k$ different orderings, since we can pick one of $k$ starting vertices for the cycle, and one of $2$ directions to go around the cycle, to obtain an ordering for it. So we must divide by $2k$ to obtain $\binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{(k-1)!}{2}$ cycles of length $k$.